# xml parsing in ios and putting parsed data in array

Tags: xml-parsing

I am trying to parse the xml file in xcode and store data in different arrays for different keys.My xml file is like as follows:

```
<Colleges>
  <College>
    <id>1</id>
    <Name>abc</Name>
    <Branches>
      <Branch>a</Branch>
      <Branch>b</Branch>
    </Branches>
  </College>
..... And many colleges....
</Colleges>
```

Can any one please give me the sample code to parse this file and put in separate arrays. I have knowledge of delegate methods but failed to implement them. I think I am lacking some were in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: [Simple XML to NSDictionary Converter](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/). The two files will help you to convert your XML data to `NSDictionary` from which you can easily get your array.